MoM comparison on Area Chart results in +1 day
I'm calculating the last 30 days vs the previous 30 days.
These are my measures:
Total Current 30 Days = 
CALCULATE(
    [Switch Currency],
    FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= TODAY() - 31 &&
        'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() - 2
    )
)

and
Total Previous 30 Days = 
CALCULATE(
    'Costs Summary Table'[Sum of measures],
    FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= TODAY() - 61 &&  -- Go back 61 days to cover a full 30-day period before the previous 30 days
        'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() - 32    -- Go back 32 days to end 31 days ago
    )
)

If I put the two on the Area Chart I see this:


Total Previous 30 Days: goes from the 25 of April till the 24 of May (29 days)
Total Current 30 Days: goes from the 25 of May till the 23 of June (29 days)

And if I check on  timeanddate.com they are really 29 days:

But if I overlap them one results in 30 days, the other in 31 days. (note I have removed the Month from the x-axis):

Where am I wrong?

Did you see the option on  timeanddate.com to include the end date in the calculation (i.e. add 1 day).

OK, but that will pass the days from 29 to 30. But still I will have the same last day of gap between the two measures in the Area Chart

You are using a categorical axis. This means each day has a "band". Power BI places a point at the centre of each band and then interpolates a line between them. i.e. the first line ends on the 24th in the middle of the band (midday) and the second line starts on the 25th in the middle of its band so a gap appears between them. Other charting solutions allow you to change how a point is plotted within a band but that is not an option here. If you want no gap, you have to end line 1 on the same day as line 2 begins.

How to end line 1 on the same day as line 2 begins?

They need to finish and start on the same day.

Ah, you mean that they should start one at the 5th of April and the other at the 5th of May?

I found a solution:
Total Current Month = CALCULATE(
    'Costs Summary Table'[Sum of measures],
     FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1) &&
        'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() -2
    )
)

And
Total Previous Month = 
CALCULATE(
    'Costs Summary Table'[Sum of measures],
    FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, 1) &&
        'Calendar'[Date] <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, DAY(TODAY()-2))
    )
)

Now, this will not compare the last 30 days but the MoM:

Special thanks to Davide Bacci
